# Resources of static html page in play 2.2.1

Tags: html, css, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have created

a static html page in a play 2.2.1 project.

My public folder looks like that:
[image]

These are my stylesheet links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/social-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/coming-soon-style.css">
```

However, when I open the site I only get the html.

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

My routes:

```
GET  /   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="comingSoon.html")
GET  /coming-soon_followUpPage.html   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="coming-soon_followUpPage.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all files/folders from `/public/assets/` directory one level higher, so for an instance instead `/public/assets/bootstrap` it should be `/public/bootstrap`

As I can see you are using default route for assets, which means that every file/folder placed in `/public` folder will be available with `assets/file` or `assets/folder` within your templates.

If you are gonna to keep them in `/public/assets/file.css` style you just need to use proper path in your templates, ie.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Anyway as you can see it doesn't make sense ;)

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried it out, however, it does not work. I only get a plain html page. Even after `play clean`...

Comment: Something wrong with your routes, I can ensure you that it NEED to work

Comment: I have updated my question, with my routes. Would appreciate if you could have a look at them...

Answer (score 1):

Hi you're linking in the wrong way your css files, you have :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

With this you're searching on the same level the folder `assets` but that is the parent and you don't need to reference this then you only need:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

You also can try adding `/` at the begin of the path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```